# When do Enumerated variable evaluate in C++

Tags: c++, enums

**Clarification** The variables set to all zeros is the case in which it breaks.  The enums with the values in comments works fine.

This is a simplification of my code, the issue being that receive the "enum error". So the question I have is when do enums get evaluated? Also, best I can figure enum are basically integers so an enum'd variable to 0 should evaluate as false and never reach the throw when I zero them all.

```
enum var_types//Set all to 0 to disable 
{
  VAR1 = 0x0,   //var1 = 0x1
  VAR2 = 0x0,   //var2 = 0x2
  VAR3 = 0x0,   //var3 = 0x3
  VAR4 = 0x0,   //var4 = 0x4
  VAR_NONE =0x0 //disabled = 0x0
};


func(int var){
  if(var){
    if(var==VAR1){ cout << VAR1 << endl;}
    else if(var==VAR2){ cout << VAR2 << endl;}
    else if(var==VAR3){ cout << VAR3 << endl;}
    else if(var==VAR4){ cout << VAR4 << endl;}
    else {throw job_error("enum error");}
  }
//doing other things...
}

func(VAR1);
func(VAR2);
func(VAR3);
func(VAR4);
func(VAR_NONE);
```

Motivation for the code is to quickly disable numerous evaluation of the "if" statement in a numerous calls to the function from a single place at the top of code, while also allowing for disabling them individually. There is approximately 15 calls to "func" in code scattered across 1200+ lines of code. The zeroing of the enums are a convenient way to disable them all from one place.

Comment: All of your enum values are forced to the same value, so what do you expect??

Comment: Enumerators are constant values. They are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Clean up your `if`s and use a `switch`.  The first `if` is extra work and does provide any significant performance gain.  A `switch` can be evaluated by table lookup or math function.

Comment: Please try to make a *compilable* example. Your code doesn't compile ("else without previous if").

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ I expect them all to evaluate as false and skip the if/else block.  As far as I have read I should be able to set them all to same value, while frowned upon, its is for debug convenience and will have the commented value under normal conditions.

Comment: @ Pete Becker thank you.

Comment: If I fix your example so it compiles I get no error, so maybe you need to show us the real code.  http://ideone.com/nxAKV1

Comment: After the edit it takes slightly less work to make your code into an actual example that compiles and runs, but when I did I still received no error. You're going to need to post a real piece of code that can bet copy/paste/compiled that demonstrates the error you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for 'VAR1..VAR4' are defined at compile time, and it is actually allowed to "zero them all out", such that `int var=0; var==VAR1; var==VAR2; ...` all evaluate to "true". The issue might be in your code, where you have `;` after each `if`, such that (once you corrected compiler errors due to misplaces `else`), you might enter all the `if`-statements.
So for the following adapted code, none of the calls yield "enum error":

```
void func(int var){
    if(var){
        if(var==VAR1){}
        else if(var==VAR2){}
        else if(var==VAR3){}
        else if(var==VAR4){}
        else {cout << "enum error";}
    }
    //doing other things...
}

int main() {    
    func(VAR2);
    func(VAR3);
    func(VAR4);
}
```

Note, however, that you usually would use the `enum`-type also as argument type. This would protect you at compile time from using "undefined enum values":

```
void func(var_types var) { ... }

int main() {

    func(1);  // Compiler error, as `1` is not a valid var_types-member
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your enum entries are explicitly assigned the value 0x0, so they are indistinguishable (and all zero).

Your comments indicate that you intend for them to have different values - and they would if you didn't assign them explicit valies.

So, if you just remove the explicit assignment of values you should get what you want.

But what I *really* want to know is; what's the *actual* problem you are trying to solve here?